# Simple MVC mod-rewrite

Tags: model-view-controller, mod-rewrite

I'm not sure how to do a mod-rewrite for a modular MVC structure.  What I want to happen is the URL captures:

`http://domainname.com/index.php?model={model}&view={view}&parameters={parameters}`
*NOTE: parameters will be in a specific order and separated by pipes (unless there is a better way):
parameters=param1|param2|param3*
`http://domainname.com/{model}/{view}/{parameters}`

Example:

`http://domainname.com/faq/edit/13`

Another Example:

`http://domainname.com/faq/index/{sort}/{page}/{search}`
`http://domainname.com/faq/index/asc/3/How+to`

Essentially anything after the model and view will and can be parameters; as many as needed. For each view I will know the possible parameters that area allowable and in what order.

Thank you in advance.

--

Using the code below this is what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*) index.php?model=$1&view=$2¶meters=$3 [L,NS]
```

URL: `http://localhost:8888/testing/faq/index/asc/5/How+to`
PHP $_GET variables:

```
Array
(
    [model] => faq/index/asc
    [view] => 5
    [parameters] => How to
)
```

Should be:

```
Array
(
    [model] => faq
    [view] => index
    [parameters] => asc/5/How to
)
```

Please help

Comment: The (.*) are greedy (i.e. they extend as much as possible). In this case, you'll have to use (.*?) for the first two. It gives you RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*)$ index.php?model=$1&view=$2&parameters=$3 [L,NS]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a PHP function to do that. Quickly, with no default value or error handling:

```
list( $controller, $function, $params ) = explode( '/', $uri, 3 );
$params = explode( '/', $uri );
```

And in the .htaccess, redirect any non-existing query to your PHP query-handling file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mvc.php [L,NS]
```

Beware to filter your input though, not to include any file, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could also have your htaccess like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*) mvc.php?model=$1&view=$2&parameters=$3 [L,NS]
```

This is just another way to do it, although personally I prefer streetpc's way.

Comment: Hey, thank you for getting back to me so quickly. I edited my question to include my tested code that I modified from what you supplied me. Almost there, just needs some tweaking. Thank you.