# MVC Ecommerce routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to get my head around routing for MVC4

I want to create a URL structure consisting of BrandName / ProductType / PageNumber

Sometimes it could just have Brand or just product type deppending on how you filter.

e.g.

> ```
> Store/{BrandName}//{PaginationId} this is unique
> Store/{ProductType}/{PaginationId} this is unique
> Store/{BrandName}/{ProductType}/{PaginationId}
> Store/{ProductType}/BrandName}/{PaginationId}
> ```

Any help?

thanks

Comment: http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/SEO-Friendly-Routes-with-ASPnet-MVC.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must register the following routes:

```
// 1: Store/ProductType/BrandName/PaginationId
// (all parts must exists in the URL)
routes.MapRoute("ProductType", "Store/{productType}/{brandName}/{paginationId}",
   new { controller = "Store", action = "Index" },
   new { /* constraints */ });

// 2: Store/BrandName/ProductType/PaginationId 
// 3: Store/BrandName/ProductType 
// 4: Store/BrandName
// (both productType and paginationId can be missing)
routes.MapRoute("BrandProduct", "Store/{brandName}/{productType}/{paginationId}",
   new { controller = "Store", action = "Index", 
         productType = UrlParameter.Optional,
         paginationId = UrlParameter.Optional},
   new { /* constraints */ });

// 5: Store/ProductType/PaginationId
// (all parts must exists in the URL)
routes.MapRoute("ProductType", "Store/{productType}/{paginationId}",
  new { controller = "Store", action = "Index", 
         brandName = 0, paginationId = 0},
  new { /* constraints */ });

// Action Index should have 3 parameters: brandName, productType and paginationId
// brandName, productType and paginationId should be nullable 
// or reference type (class) to accept nulls
```

When an URL is received, the first route that matches it will handle it. So there must be a way to distinguish the routes. This can be done using constraints. A constraint is a regex which decides if the received value is valid for a parameter.

Suppose that in the first mapping the ProductType must be something starting with "P", you would add this constraint: new `{productType="P.*"}`:

- If the user types this URL: /Store/P22/TheBrand/12, it will be processed by the first route
- If the user types this URL: /Store/TheBrand/P22/12, it won't be processed bythe first route because of the constraint, but will be processed by the second one.

You must disambiguate routes 1 & 2, and also routes 3 & 5

If there is no regex that can do that for you, you can modify the routes with some extra chars that allow to disimbiguate them, ie, put P- and B- before product type nad brand name, like this:

```
// 1:
routes.MapRoute("ProductType", "Store/P-{productType}/B-{brandName}/{paginationId}",

// 2, 3, 4
routes.MapRoute("BrandProduct", "Store/B-{brandName}/P-{productType}/{paginationId}",
```

Remember that the routes are processed in the same order in which they are registered.

**EDIT - Answer to OP comment:**

If you just want a behaviour similar to ASP.NET, where a single page uses all the info, then use this mapping:

```
routes.MapRoute("Store", "Store", new {controller="Store",action="Index"}}
```

With this mapping, all the extra information will end up in the query string like this:

```
http://mysite/Store?ProductType=xxx&BrandName=yyy&PaginationId=23
```

If you don't provide some of the parameters, they will be simply omitted from the query string.

The action would look like this:

```
Index(string brandName, string prouctType, int? paginationId)
```

Note that, as all parameters are optional, they must be nullable (reference type like `string` or nullable value type like `int?`). So they'll be automatically bound from the query string, or left null if not present.

There is no reason why *you must* use Routing. *You can* use routing to get "smart" urls, but you don't need to.

Comment: Thanks, It all seems terrible long winded for something so trivial. I can do this in PHP and ASP.NET Webforms but it seems that MVC does this overly complicated.

Comment: No, it's not MVC fault. If you don't use route parts, the parameters will end up in the querystring, and then you have the same behavior of ASP.NET (and PHP, I suppose). See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Create a "main" browsing controller, and make `BrandName`, `ProductType` and `PaginationId` be parameters.

Result:

```
Store/Browse?BrandName=XX&ProductType=YY&PaginationId=ZZ
```

You can then overlap some [URL-Rewriting logic (link to other SO answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991063/simple-mvc-mod-rewrite) to achieve the required URL structure.

For cases when a parameter would be missing, I suggest setting them to a default value: for example, if you would not have `ProductType`, you could do this:

```
Store/Browse?BrandName=XX&ProductType=ALL&PaginationId=ZZ
```

In short: if it's missing, default its value and make it so you always have values everywhere they can be. Easier to handle and easier to understand too.