# .htaccess routing in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a customized framework. My directory structure is:

```
root
->private
  ->www
    ->controllers
      ->load.php
      ->router.php
    ->views
      ->home.php
      ->sign-up.php

->index.php
->htaccess.php
```

when i type www.mysite.com, the home.php page is displayed. In the home-page i have a sign-up button. `<li><a href="sign-up.php">Sign-Up</a></li>`
On click, i want the .htaccess file to route this request to sign-up.php under the views folder.
My current htaccess file looks like:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .pl .cgi
Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

What am i doing wrong/not doing to get what i want???
m stuck.help!

Comment: Your regex in the rule doesn't contain the hyphen that is in `sign-up.php`. I don't know if that is *the* problem, but it is a problem.

Comment: @jon what do i do to add a hyphen?

Comment: i had done it this way sometime back...it worked then...but don't seem to get tgru this time

Comment: i changed it to 'signup.php'...it doesn't help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple MVC mod-rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991063/simple-mvc-mod-rewrite)

Comment: @spyder: What should be internal URI for `/signup`?

Comment: www.mysite.com/signup.php

Answer (score 0):

Insert this additional rule just below `RewriteEngine on`:

```
# To internally forward file to /views/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/views/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /views/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Won't this circumvent his front controller and sort of defeat the hole MVC pattern?

Comment: Ok let me clarify with OP

Comment: i want to route every request to (root) index.php to load.php (which will load the corresponding template and model file) using the router.php (which will actually parse the REQUEST_URI and tell load.php of the specific files to load)

Comment: Yes that's what I tried asking what exactly is the full internal URI for `/signup`. It can be something like `/router.php?action=signup`